# Parse JObject in another JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using Json.net and this is my json:

```
{
    "miner": "t1biSMuXyq5eKkP8zDPViKHF9mbS9ZFLRuF",
    "totalHash": 1523943880.832757,
    "totalShares": 4089.53223605,
    "networkSols": "7644579",
    "immature": 0.29784511,
    "balance": 0,
    "paid": 1092.22974323,
    "workers": {
        "t1biSMuXyq5eKkP8zDPViKHF9mbS9ZFLRuF": {
            "name": "t1biSMuXyq5eKkP8zDPViKHF9mbS9ZFLRuF",
            "diff": 54500,
            "shares": 106.44625040000004,
            "invalidshares": 0,
            "currRoundShares": 4082.8793454,
            "currRoundTime": 0,
            "hashrate": 1523943880.832757,
            "hashrateString": "3.05 KSol/s",
            "luckDays": "5.574",
            "luckHours": "133.768",
            "paid": 1092.22974323,
            "balance": 0
        }
    },
    "history": {
        "t1biSMuXyq5eKkP8zDPViKHF9mbS9ZFLRuF": [
            {
                "time": 1516522247,
                "hashrate": 1600923951.4915187
            },
            {
                "time": 1516526867,
                "hashrate": 1523943880.832757
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to get element hashrateString inside "workers" and inside "t1biSMuXyq5eKkP8zDPViKHF9mbS9ZFLRuF" but the "t1biSMuXyq5eKkP8zDPViKHF9mbS9ZFLRuF" changes every time.

This is my current code:

```
String dl = webClient.DownloadString("http://hushpool.cloud/api/worker_stats?t1biSMuXyq5eKkP8zDPViKHF9mbS9ZFLRuF");
JObject json = JObject.Parse(dl);
JObject workers = JObject.Parse(JObject.Parse(dl).SelectToken("workers").First.ToString());
label7.Text = (String)json.GetValue("balance");
label8.Text = (String)json.GetValue("pending");
label9.Text = (String)json.GetValue("paid");
label10.Text = (String)workers.GetValue("hashrateString");
```

I've tried different codes but nothing worked. Could you guys help me?

Comment: I've cut down the json to bare essentials, and formatted it a bit so its easier to understand. If you feel like something is missing, please put it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `minerValue` is not constant, you need to get it from the json in the first place and use it to traverse the `JObject` to get the value of the `hashrateString`

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
JObject workers = (JObject)obj.GetValue("workers");
string minerValue = obj.GetValue("miner").ToString();
JObject minerWorker = (JObject)workers.GetValue(minerValue);
string hashRate = minerWorker.GetValue("hashrateString").ToString();
```

Update:
Per your comment, if there is a scenario in which property name will be slightly different, you may use following code to get the object:

```
JObject workerMiner = (JObject)workers.Properties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.StartsWith(minerValue)).Value;
```

Keep in mind that this code is not production ready since you need to handle corner/faulty cases (e.g. *worker* or *miner* properties do not exist in json)

Comment: The problem is when "miner" value is not the same as value of the first worker. In some cases "miner" value can be: t1biSMuXyq5eKkP8zDPViKHF9mbS9ZFLRuF but first element in "workers" can be: t1biSMuXyq5eKkP8zDPViKHF9mbS9ZFLRuF.worker1

Comment: @TomažČuk please look at the updated answer, basically `workers` object will be traversed and first property which starts with "t1biSMuXyq5eKkP8zDPViKHF9mbS9ZFLRuF" will be returned.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to retrieve `'hashratestring'` from you json text using jsonpath.

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonTxt);
string name = (string)obj.SelectToken("$.workers.*.hashrateString");
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Output:

```
3.05 KSol/s
```

Working sample at https://dotnetfiddle.net/wl7fUw